# Binomial expansion, how to do them quickly?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I'm currently preparing for a test where I'm bound to do a couple of binomial expansions. Since I never encountered them in my formal education, I looked how to do them myself and found out:

$ (x+y)^n = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^k y^{n-k} $

I'm using this formula for my binomial expansion, but this takes a long time, especially to calculate the binomial coefficient (we aren't allowed to use a calculator).

Consider the following (easy) example: *Write down the binomial expansion of $(4+x)^4$, and hence evaluate $(4.2)^2$ to 2 decimal places.*

I use the above formula  to get $256 + 256x + 96x^2+16x^3 + x^4$. Fill in for $x=0.2$.

- Here I encounter my first problems: How do you know how many terms to use when you are told to evaluate to $n$ decimal places?
- Unrelated to the title: $(4.2)^4 = 311.1696$. When you use 4 terms you get $311.168$. Would the correct answer be $311.16...$ or $\approx 311.17$?
- Are there other, quicker ways of doing binomial expansions, which can rid me of the problem of binomial coefficients?

Comment: Do you know Pascal's triangle? That's essential.

Comment: @DonLarynx Yes, I do.

Comment: Since $(0.2)^4=0.0016<0.005$, the $x^4$ term can’t affect the second decimal place, so the first four terms suffice, and you need only round $311.168$ to two decimal places, getting $311.17$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks, I realized that just a moment ago. Also, thanks for answering the second question. I thought the correct answer could only be $311.16..$, because that is correct up to 2 d.p. while $311.17$ is rounded up.

Comment: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose I wanted to expand $(x + 4)^4$. Using the above formula, $x = x$ and $y = 4$. So

$${4\choose0}x^44^0 + {4\choose1}x^34^1 + {4\choose2}x^24^2 + {4\choose3}x^14^3 + {4\choose4}x^04^4$$

Knowing Pascal's triangle, I can use $1, 4, 6, 4, 1$ as my coefficients. So the answer is 
$$x^4 + 16x^3 + 96x^2 + 256x + 256.$$

> Here I encounter my first problems: How do you know how many terms to use when you are told to evaluate to n decimal places?

In terms of $x$, you go down from $x^n$ to $x^0.$ I feel as if I misunderstood this question, however.

> Unrelated to the title: (4.2)4=311.1696. When you use 4 terms you get 311.168. Would the correct answer be 311.16... or ≈311.17?

It doesn't really matter here, but when rounding, it's 311.17. 168 is over 165, which rounds t0 170.

> Are there other, quicker ways of doing binomial expansions, which can rid me of the problem of binomial coefficients?

Not that I know of.

Comment: But in this case, when we go down from $x^2$ to $x^0$, we have 3 terms which gives us an answer of $307.328$, which isn't accurate at all..

Comment: @Phaptitude Can you be more clear?

Comment: I'll try to rephrase my question: When they ask for a binomial expansion, they usually also ask for a certain accuracy, to $x$ decimal places. My question is, how do you know how many terms of a binomial expansion to use when you are asked for a certain amount of decimal places?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by terms.

Comment: $4x^4$ is a term. So is $16x^3$. I thought that was common terminology.

Comment: @Phaptitude: It is common terminology.

Comment: @Don: Your first term should be $x^4$: $\binom404^0=1$.

Comment: @DonLarynx Nevermind that question, I just found out why it's not really that hard. Thanks for the pascal triangle help!

Answer (score 10):

Sorry if there is a rule against posting on questions that have not been active lately, feel free to delete if there is, but I thought this method might be helpful for someone else who doesn't want to look at Pascal's triangle or won't be given it in a test.

Here is a well-known alternative method you might find faster. Let
$$\binom{n}{k}:=m_k.$$ Then
$$\frac{m_{k+1}}{m_k}=\frac{k!\left(n-k\right)!}{\left(k+1\right)!\left(n-k-1\right)!}=\frac{n-k}{k+1}.$$ This means if you know one coefficient you can calculate all the rest, by multiplying the first coefficient $m_k$ by the corresponding index $n-k,$ then dividing by the number of terms you have in the sum so far, $k+1.$ So for example, if you have $$(a+b)^n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}b^k,$$ then if we take $n=37,$ you know $(a+b)^{37}=a^{37}+\cdots,$ so your first coefficient is $1.$ It corresponds to the index $n-k=37,$ and you have one term so far. So, your next coefficient is
$$1\times\frac{37}{1}=37.$$ Next, $37\times36/2=666.$ The fourth coefficient is $666\times35/3=7770,$ getting $$(a+b)^{37}=a^{37}+37a^{36}b+666a^{35}b^2+7770a^{34}b^3+\cdots$$and so on until you get half of them and then use the symmetrical nature of the binomial theorem to write down the other half.